# Sending message to IoTHub fails

Tags: azure, client, azure-iot-hub

I have been working on a device which is sending some data to an Azure IoT hub 
The device is doing this on two different locations in the code. On one side it works perfectly and I can connect to the Hub via Connection String and transport type MQTT_WebSocket_Only.

```
public static class Mqtt2IoTNew
{
    private static string _DeviceConnectionString = Properties.Settings.Default.MqttUri;

    private static TransportType _TransportType = TransportType.Mqtt_WebSocket_Only;

   public static void Send(object argEntry, bool argIsList)
    {
        var deviceClient = DeviceClient.CreateFromConnectionString(_DeviceConnectionString, _TransportType);
        deviceClient.ReceiveAsync(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(2)).Wait();

        var message = new Message(deviceClient, argEntry, argIsList);
        message.RunAsync().GetAwaiter().GetResult();
    }

}

internal class Message
{
    private DeviceClient _DeviceClient;
    private readonly string _Message;

    public Message(DeviceClient argDeviceClient, object argEntry, bool isList)
    {
        _DeviceClient = argDeviceClient;
        StringBuilder stb = new StringBuilder();
        if (isList)
        {
            foreach (var entity in (List<object>) argEntry)
            {
                stb.Append("<entity>").Append(JsonConvert.SerializeObject(entity)).Append("</entity>\n");
            }
        }
        else
        {
            stb.Append(JsonConvert.SerializeObject(argEntry));
        }
        _Message = stb.ToString();
    }

    public async Task RunAsync()
    {
        await SendEvent().ConfigureAwait(false);
    }

    private async Task SendEvent()
    {
        Microsoft.Azure.Devices.Client.Message eventMessage = new Microsoft.Azure.Devices.Client.Message(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(_Message));
        await _DeviceClient.SendEventAsync(eventMessage).ConfigureAwait(false);
    }
}



//Call of method that does not work
    protected override void DoOnCompleted(IRepository argRepository)
    {
        if (_CurrentlySendingTreadId.HasValue)
        {
            if (_CurrentlySendingTreadId.Value == Thread.CurrentThread.ManagedThreadId)
            {
                return;
            }
        }

        TaskFactoryProvider.GetFactory().StartNew(()=>SendBatchProtocols());
    }

    public bool SendBatchProtocols()
    {
        using (var repository = RepositoryProviderHolder.RepositoryProvider.GetRepository(Constants.CONTAINERCONTRACT_PRODUCTIONREPOSITORY))
        {
            IQueryable<BatchProtocol> batchProtocolQuery = repository.GetQuery<BatchProtocol>().OrderBy(bp => bp.InternalNoInteger);
            batchProtocolQuery = batchProtocolQuery.Where(bp => !bp.IsArchived).Take(1);

            if (!batchProtocolQuery.Any()) return false;

            var batchProtocols = batchProtocolQuery.ToList();
            IsBatchProtocolSend = false;
            try
            {
                foreach (var bps in batchProtocols)
                {
                    Mqtt2IoTNew.Send(bps,false);
                }
                IsBatchProtocolSend = true;
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                throw;
            }
        }
        return IsBatchProtocolSend;
    }

//Call of Method that does work
    private void AddEntitiesAndSaveChanges(IEnumerable argEntities)
    {
        if (argEntities == null)
        {
            return;
        }

        lock (_UnderlyingRepositoryAccessLockObject)
        {
            #region Log2DornerIoT


            if (Properties.Settings.Default.Log2DornerIoT)
            {
                List<object> entities = new List<object>();
                int i = 0;
                foreach (var entity in argEntities)
                {
                    if (i < 100)
                    {
                        entities.Add(entity);
                        i++;
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        try
                        {
                            Mqtt2IoTNew.Send(entities, true);
                        }
                        catch (Exception e)
                        {
                            throw;
                        }
                        entities.Clear();
                        i = 0;
                    }
                }
            }
        }
```

on the other part of the code, I am only colling the same class to use to send method in the same way but here I get an exception which says "TLS authentication error" and the inner exception "Unable to connect to the remote server", "The underlying connection was closed: Could not establish trust relationship for the SSL/TLS secure channel".

But: I never used any kind of authorization not in the first part which works perfectly neither in the second.

I would be very happy if someone could help me. I have found nothing so fare regarding this issue.

Thanks for your time. 
Michael

Comment: we won't be able to help if you don't post relevant source code

Comment: Sorry now I have edited the post hopefully it helps. Thanks!

Comment: so which part is running fine and which part is not?

Comment: Second Methodcall works first does not

Comment: where is this class defined? `Mqtt2IoTNew` Your entire code is very hard to read btw

Comment: I have found a mistake I will try something out and come back
Any suggestions on cleaner code?

Comment: many... fix your error, update your code above and I can see if I can get you a revised version

Comment: I have changed the code but still have the same issue

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the reason why it didn't work. There was a Persmissice Certificate Policy applied that blocked the certificate at one side of the project. I disabled it and now it works perfectly fine.
Thanks for the help anyway.